# Sum involving complex roots and binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation

Suppose I have the following.  First, let $\zeta_m=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}}$.  Then I am trying to find the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(\zeta_m^k+1\right)^n$$
for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  So I know that by the Binomial Theorem I can make this
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^n{\binom{n}{j}\zeta_m^{jk}}=\sum_{j=0}^n{\binom{n}{j}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\zeta_m^{jk}$$
Now by because $\zeta_m$ is a complex root of unity, the sums of it's powers are either $0$ if $m\not|j$ or $m$ if $m|j$.  So I thought then I could simplify by saying 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n{\binom{n}{j}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\zeta_m^{jk}=\sum_{j=0, m|j}^n\binom{n}{j}m$$
But how can I simplify here?  Or is there a better way to evaluate this sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes helps to write $\zeta_m+1=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}}+1=e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{m}}+e^{-\frac{i\pi}{m}}\right)$

Comment: So I should use $(-1)^{1/m}(2\cos{(\pi/m)})$?

Comment: Try it and see - I'm a bit rusty but recall the substitution being useful